# ffmpeg : is there a simple way to edit the video resolution, but keep all audio and subtitles

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, filtering, resolution, video-subtitles

I would like to lower video resolution - usually from `.mkv` files - but to keep all possible audio tracks (might be only one, might be several) and subtitles (might be none, might be several) from the original one. I also would like to keep as many encoding parameters as I can from the original video file (especially those I do not understand).

I am still new to ffmpeg : at first the idea seemed simple, but after many attempts, it seems it is more complex than that. Do I have to use the [`-filter_complex`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Filtergraph-description) option ? It seems to be an overkill (or overcomplex) for what I thought to be an easy conversion, but I might be wrong.

I tried to combine `-vf scale=-1:720` with `-c copy -map 0`, which gave me an error that I now understand, but I am stuck with the next step.

Any lead on to achieve that ? Could it be done with ffmpeg only or would I need a script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your try should've worked. For example,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=-1:720 -map 0 -c:a copy -c:s copy output.mp4
```

grabs all the streams from the input, passes all video streams through the scale filter, and copies all audio and subtitle streams.

What was the error?

> keep as many encoding parameters

This it cannot do. When you reencode, it's on you to pick the parameters to best match those possibly used for the input.

Comment: Working great, thank you sir ! I was using `-vf scale=-1:720 -c copy -map 0`, I missed the `-c:a` and `-c:s` options. I was actually trying to copy *all* steams, and ffmpeg error indicates that : **Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.**